# Npm install is installing partial packages and then throwing error

Tags: npm

```js
PS D:\Latest_Workspace\LLA-monorepo> npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: lla@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@12.2.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"12.2.13" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"^11.0.0" from @ngrx/effects@11.0.0
npm ERR!   @ngrx/effects@"11.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ravishankar.c.PRODAPT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ravishankar.c.PRODAPT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-01-31T18_22_27_563Z-debug.log
```

This error occurred while trying to install node_modules.

[To edit: Please add some more details about what you were trying to do, and how this error occurred.]

Comment: Please add some proper context on what you were trying to do, and what problem raised, also with Angular version that you have on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` flag. If that does not work try downgrading your npm version.

Check out [here](https://exerror.com/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages/)